# Coin Change Problem with Fixed Coins

Tags: algorithms, approximation, integer-partitions, integers, np-complete

**Problem**: Given $n$ coin denominations, with $c_1<c_2<c_3<\cdots<c_{n}$ being positive integer numbers, and a number $X$, we want to know whether the number $X$ can be changed by $N$ coins.

Note that $N$ is fixed.
There are infinite number coins for each coin denomination.
For a coin denomination, more than one coins would be used to change $X$.

This problem is related to coin change problem, multiple-choice knapsack problem, $0$-$1$ knapsack problem, postage stamp problem, etc. However, it has differences with these problems.

Is this problem NP-complete?

How to solve this problem?

If you have ideas and suggestions, it's pleasure if you can share with me.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You've described an NP-complete problem. Indeed, this problem is exactly the [subset-sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) with the extra restriction that the desired subset has size $N$; but if this were not NP-complete then the subset-sum problem would not be either, because it would only take $|C|$ iterations of the "change-problem" algorithm to solve subset-sum (where $C$ is the set of coins). Subset-sum [is NP-complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10702/proving-np-completeness-of-a-subset-sum-problem-how).

Actually, I've ignored that coins must have positive denomination. [It remains NP-complete](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101971/subset-sum-problem-when-the-number-of-integers-in-the-sum-is-known).

Comment: Thanks very much!  In the proposed problem, we assume that there are  infinite number coins for each coin denomination. Moreover, in the subset with sum $X$, there may have more than one coins with the same  denomination. Therefore, it would not only take |C| iterations of the "change-problem" algorithm to solve subset-sum (where C is the set of coins)

Comment: We don't need infinitely many coins - we only need $X/{c_1}$ of them.